# Move map markers using location data from Firebase - GeoFire on Google Map iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, google-maps-sdk-ios, geofire

I'm developing iOS Taxi application which uses Google Map SDK, Firebase and Geofire. I need to show realtime movements of taxi drivers around passenger location, when he/she changes his pickup location on the map (This happens before passenger calls for hire, just to check drivers vicinity around users location ).

I've successfully integrated geofire to the application but I want to know how to move markers smoothly on the map. Is it only way to remove all markers on the map and add them again one by one, which I see as a bad implementation. Is there any better options?

```
//The location of a key now matches the query criteria.
GFQuery *query = [geoFire queryAtLocation:L(coor.latitude, coor.longitude) withRadius:1];
[query observeEventType:GFEventTypeKeyEntered withBlock:^(NSString *key, CLLocation *location) {
    NSLog(@"Entered Key '%@' entered the search area and is at location '%@'", key, location);
    //Remove all markers and add location received from this block?
}];

//The location of a key no longer matches the query criteria.
[query observeEventType:GFEventTypeKeyExited withBlock:^(NSString *key, CLLocation *location) {
    NSLog(@"Exited Key '%@' entered the search area and is at location '%@'", key, location);
    //Remove all markers and add location received from this block?
}];

//The location of a key changed but the location still matches the query criteria.
[query observeEventType:GFEventTypeKeyMoved withBlock:^(NSString *key, CLLocation *location) {
    NSLog(@"Moved Key '%@' entered the search area and is at location '%@'", key, location);
    //Remove all markers and add location received from this block?
}];
```

Please if someone have done this before give some example code snippet to implement this in a better way.

Comment: May be this will help a bit - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27394656/need-to-add-a-fixed-overlay-like-on-mapview-in-ios/27395137#27395137

Comment: Thank you Kampai, I will look into this.

Answer (score 0):

Removing all markers on the map and add them again, will be seriously bad solution. You can use position property of GMSMarker to move your marker, and CATransaction to give moving effect.

```
Eg. Mall moveMarkerPositionWithMotion method to change location of your marker

-(void)moveMarkerPositionWithMotion {
    [CATransaction begin];
    NSTimeInterval nAnimationDuration = 1; // Update this value as per your needs.
    [CATransaction setAnimationDuration:nAnimationDuration];
    marker.position = coordindates;
    [CATransaction commit];
}
```

Comment: Hi Nikdange_me, Thank you. With using above blocks from geofire (key and current location receiving) provided and https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/marker#remove_a_marker what is the implementation/pseudocode I should do? Can you please provide some snippets?

Comment: in which block do you receive location of taxi? @happycoder

Comment: I'm still working on it, I already knew how to move a marker from an animation, I need of populating markers smoothly with given geofire   blocks (removing and adding them efficiently). I will update once I found one.

Comment: Please read my question: "Is it only way to remove all markers on the map and add them again one by one, which I see as a bad implementation. Is there any better options? Please if someone have done this before give some example code snippet to implement this in a better way."

Comment: so what i tried to answer is "I want to know how to move markers smoothly on the map " &" without removing and and adding marker again"! @happycoder